# How to make a scatter-plot if I have more than one treatment?

Tags: r

here is my question.
I would like to make a scatterplot which (x,y) pairs are connected by line.
I have three treatments A,B,and C

```
A<-c(103.4,102.5,101.4,101.0,98.8)
B<-c(102.9,101.6,101.4,100.3,99.6)
C<-c(103.9,103.1,102.3,100.4,97.6)
```

These 3 variables are going to be plotted on the y axis (Temperature)
And I also have a variable for the x axis (Minutes)

```
M<-c(15,30,45,60,75)
```

I just would like to know how to make a plot using different lines and symbols for the 3 different treatments.
Thanks so much!

Comment: You find several possibilities [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519873/how-to-create-a-line-plot-with-groups-in-base-r-without-loops)

Answer (score 2):

```
png()  # default file name is "Rplot001.png" in your working directory
matplot(M, cbind(A,B,C), type="b", 
        xlab= "Minutes", ylab=expression(Temperature~degree*F), 
        xlim=range(M)+c(-5,5), ylim=range(c(A,B,C)) +c(-1,1) )
dev.off()
# See ?legend and ?title for further annotation
```

[image]